# Is it possible to specify branch name on first commit in git?

Tags: git, branch

is it possible to perform a first commit on a new repository using a different branch name than "master" ? Thank you

Comment: You can commit to `master` and then rename the branch. Isn't that working for you?

Comment: I've found this:

`git branch -m master newbranchname`

But... is there some way to specify the branch name in the first commit?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes. Before you make any commit you can just do `git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/not-master`. This changes the name of the branch that you are on (that has no commits).

Answer (score 10):

Certainly - when the git repository is empty there are no branches. Just HEAD points to `refs/heads/master` which will be the first branch created by the first commit. If you are using git >= 1.7.10 you can create a branch before the first commit that gets used instead of master (`git checkout -b dev`) and you don't get a master branch created.

Comment: I can't create a branch before the first commit for the same reason Charles specified

Comment: I wonder if that is version dependent -- with Git 1.7.11.msysgit.0 it works fine to create a branch immediately after initalizing the repository.

Comment: Yes, maybe was that, cause I'm using Git 1.7.7.5